# Installing from a specific branch in GitHub. Do I need to specify egg?

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I want to install the [2.3 branch](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/tree/2.3) of [PyMC](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc).

I have tried with:

```
pip install -e git+git:://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3
```

and

```
pip install git+git:://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3
```

without luck. Do I need to specify `egg` information? If so why?

Comment: *without luck* - What happened? When asking a question on StackOverflow, try to give **all** the relevant information you can - it makes it easier for people to help and more likely you'll get a useful response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many colons in your URL:

```
git+git:://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3
#  ----^
```

Just *one* colon is required:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3
```

or, in editable mode:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc@2.3
```

Provided you have a Fortran compiler installed that Just Works.

The `#egg=<projectname>` part is optional and only used to test for dependencies before downloading. It lets pip test if the package is already installed without needing to clone the whole repository.